# Controlling scope in Java EE projects

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, annotations, scope

What is the method of controlling scope in Java EE projects. I'm reading about session, request, application scope and that certain beans should be limited to one or the other. How is this generally done? Is it by what type of project the bean is created in, a special annotation, or some other method? In my experience I've noticed that when outside of the same package none of my beans, servlets or DAO's have access to each other unless I inject or import the related class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing things. The scopes you listed are for JSF backing beans and are generally related to the HTTP session or request. EJB-s has no scope in this context. To use them they have to be injected using DI annotations (or alternatively via JNDI context lookup).

Comment: I'm starting to learn about JSF after having implemented a form of MVC with a database and entities, EJBs, and servlets/jsp. I'm struggling to fit JSF in this model.

Comment: They do not fit in the JSF model, at least not tightly. JSF components can use EJB components, but this is optional from both ends of the relationship. Basically JSF is just JSP with a lifecycle model, dependency injection and some new tags... What you should understand is how dependency injection works, since that connects these two separate technologies.

Comment: you mean like @EJB MyEJB myejb;   ?

Comment: Also to anyone else reading this that might have had the same confusion I just read that there is an annotation @ ViewScoped, @ RequestScoped, that I believe control these scopes for JSF managed beans.

Comment: Yes. I suggest you to read about the JSF lifecycle and framework, I think it'll help to understand these things.

Answer (score 1):

Scope refers to how long a variable lives and is available for use.  Within a Java web app there are four scopes: Page, Request, Session and Application.  For variables/objects that have Page scope, they exist only within the JSP page. Any object or variable that is created within a JSP has Page scope by default.

Request scope variables/objects live as long as the Request is valid-- remember that a request may span more than one JSP/Servlet.

Session scope objects live and are accessible via all across all Requests, JSPs and Servlets for the duration of a session.  A 'session' is typically all the pages that a user views during a login session.

Application scope objects and variables are global in scope and are around as long as the application is running. They are accessible from all Requests, JSPs, Servlets, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing EE scope with class/package/etc. scope.

Objects can be exposed to JSP pages (or other view-layer technology) by putting them in one of the scopes you mention. It's not related to Java package/class visibility, but whether the object is available to the entire `application`, the current user's `session`, the current `request`, or the current `page`.

Application scope lives for the duration of the app. Session scope is specific to a particular user's "conversation" with the app--it's why we need a session cookie or URL re-writing (the `jsessionid` thing). Request scope lasts the duration of a user's specific request, and is also specific to a particular user. Page scope... honestly, I'm not sure how often its used.