# Will my Java based website be available for thousands of users while, I am coding like if there is only one user accessing the resources at a time?

Tags: java, tomcat, web, jakarta-ee, server

After learning advance Java, I am creating my first website in Java using Tomcat server. But it seems like I am creating my website in such a way that there is only one user accessing the resources. Will my website work, when thousands of users would be accessing my website? Will it be handled by Tomcat anyhow or do I have to write code thousands of times so that thousands of users can access it at the same time?

Comment: should work for multiple users. You can go to the docs of server and framework you are using to find a basic example. Also show some code you have written so that we can know if there is anything wrong with it.

Comment: You might be interested in variable scopes on a web app. There are four: Page, Request, Session and Application. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158144/controlling-scope-in-java-ee-projects

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat will delegate a thread from a threadpool to each incoming http request and the same code you wrote will run in parallel for many users at the same time.

So the short answer is you don't have to worry about it. The longer answer would involve considering performance and business logic issues. For example if you are setting up a web shop, you don't want to sell the same TV to multiple people at the same time.

If you have any more specific questions maybe post those so we can give more specific answers.

Comment: Thank you for clearing my doubt.
And for the TV problem, I have read something like "synchronization" concept. Perhaps I have to make the resource thread safe, I guess. Am I right?